# What is the formal definition of a structure?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

I can't seem to find one anywhere, and I've looked in several books and pages. I don't even know how to tag this.

Comment: You mean like in here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_(mathematical_logic)?

Comment: Structure is a set or a class that interprets (is a model) of a certain First-Order Language

Comment: @Hayden Well, more like in here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_structure, I wasn't thinking about it like in logic

Comment: I tagged the question as it [currently is](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1029937/2) because of the the tag (meta-math). It seems I misinterpreted your intention. **Edit:** I have [now fixed the question](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1029937/3) to suit what seems to me is your intent.

Comment: I believe there is something like this in Bourbaki's first book